# How do i instantiate a spring service in a standalone client

Tags: java, spring, osgi, instantiation

We have a Service as a OSGi bundle deployed on a Virgo server and is running ACTIVE. What is the procedure to instantiate it in a Standalone client.

(Client can be run on the same machine as the server is running)

Thanks.

Comment: Is the standalone client to use OSGi as well?

Comment: @skaffman, not necessarily.. bt it is ok tu be OSGi...

Comment: There is not enough information here. What kind of service are you talking about? If the service is `ACTIVE`, then it already is instantiated. What do actually want? What do you mean by a *Standalone client*?

Answer (score 0):

You should use ServiceTracker in order to get reference to the service you have deployed.